# Reasons for CPU usage drop - and raise when running multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, scheduler, thread-priority

I observe strange behavior when running a multi-threaded simulation. In the beginning, all computation threads are maxed out. Then after some frames, some of the threads reduces their workload on the CPU to one fourth, while one thread remains maxed out. After further steps, all threads maxes out again. I observe the same effect in both Windows and Linux. What can cause a thread that continues to run the same code to get that lower CPU usage (one fourth) for a longer while and then return to its maximum?

The simulation is done on a 2d domain (a matrix) is divided into N stripes, where N equals the number of threads. After each frame, the threads are synchronized and the buffers are swapped. It is observed that the framerate is reduced by the same order as the maximum CPU usage. The threads process the following code:

```
void Sim2d::Test_ModelState::process(uintmax_t framecounter
,const Bufferinfo& buffer_src,Bufferinfo& buffer_dest
,unsigned int offset)
{       
auto ptr_dest=buffer_dest.bufferGet<Test_PixelData>();
auto ptr_src=buffer_src.bufferGet<Test_PixelData>();

auto W=buffer_dest.widthGet<Test_PixelData>();
auto h=buffer_dest.heightGet();
auto H=buffer_src.heightGet();

auto F=m_params.feed_rate;
auto ka=m_params.decay_rate;
auto d=m_params.diff_ratio;
auto k_start=offset==0?1:0;


for(uint32_t k=k_start; k<h && k+offset<H-1; ++k)
    {
    for(uint32_t l=1;l<W-1;++l)
        {
        auto dyy_u=ptr_src[k+offset+1][l].u - 2*ptr_src[k+offset][l].u
            + ptr_src[k+offset-1][l].u;
        auto dxx_u=ptr_src[k+offset][l+1].u - 2*ptr_src[k+offset][l].u
            + ptr_src[k+offset][l-1].u;

        auto dyy_v=ptr_src[k+offset+1][l].v - 2*ptr_src[k+offset][l].v
            + ptr_src[k+offset-1][l].v;
        auto dxx_v=ptr_src[k+offset][l+1].v - 2*ptr_src[k+offset][l].v
            + ptr_src[k+offset][l-1].v;

        auto l_u=dxx_u+dyy_u;
        auto l_v=dxx_v+dyy_v;

        auto v_u=ptr_src[k+offset][l].u;
        auto v_v=ptr_src[k+offset][l].v;

        ptr_dest[k][l].u=v_u + 0.06125*( d*l_u - v_u*v_v*v_v + F*(1-v_u) );
        ptr_dest[k][l].v=v_v + 0.06125*( l_v + v_u*v_v*v_v - (F+ka)*v_v );

        }
    ptr_dest[k][0]=ptr_dest[k][1];
    ptr_dest[k][W-1]=ptr_dest[k][W-2];
    }

if(offset + h == H)
    {
    for(uint32_t l=0;l<W;++l)
        {ptr_dest[h-1][l]=ptr_dest[h-2][l];}
    }
if(offset==0)
    {
    for(uint32_t l=0;l<W;++l)
        {ptr_dest[0][l]=ptr_dest[1][l];}
    }

}
```

The loops updates the data block assigned to current thread. This block starts offset rows down the matrix. The reason for passing the entire matrix as input buffer is for supporting periodic boundary condition (The example uses Neumann conditions).

The two buffers are managed by two BufferinfoPair objects that are swapped between two frames

```
namespace Sim2d
{
struct BufferinfoPair
    {
    BufferinfoPair(Vector::MatrixStorage<ValueType>& matrix_first
        ,Vector::MatrixStorage<ValueType>& matrix_second
        ,uint32_t height_block,uint32_t offset);

    Bufferinfo first;
    Bufferinfo second;
    };

inline void swap(BufferinfoPair& a,BufferinfoPair& b)
    {
    ::std::swap(a.first.m_buffer,b.first.m_buffer);
    ::std::swap(a.second.m_buffer,b.second.m_buffer);
    }
}

Sim2d::BufferinfoPair::BufferinfoPair(
 Vector::MatrixStorage<ValueType>& matrix_first
,Vector::MatrixStorage<ValueType>& matrix_second
,uint32_t height_block,uint32_t offset):
first
    {
     matrix_first.rowsGet()
    ,uint32_t(matrix_first.nColsGet())
    ,uint32_t(matrix_first.nRowsGet())
    }
,second
    {
     matrix_second.rowsGet()+offset
    ,uint32_t(matrix_second.nColsGet())
    ,uint32_t(height_block)
    }
{}
```

where `Bufferinfo` looks like

```
namespace Sim2d
{
class BufferinfoPair;
void swap(BufferinfoPair& a,BufferinfoPair& b);

class Bufferinfo
    {
    public:
        Bufferinfo(ValueType* const* buffer,uint32_t width,uint32_t height)
            :m_buffer(buffer),m_width(width),m_height(height)
            {}

        template<class T>
        const T* const* bufferGet() const
            {return (const T* const*)m_buffer;}

        template<class T>
        T* const* bufferGet() 
            {return (T* const*)m_buffer;}

        template<class T>
        uint32_t widthGet() const
            {return m_width/ (sizeof(T)/sizeof(ValueType));}

        uint32_t heightGet() const
            {return m_height;}

    private:
        ValueType* const* m_buffer;
        uint32_t m_width;
        uint32_t m_height;

        friend void swap(BufferinfoPair& a,BufferinfoPair& b);          
    };
}
```

Finally, the main loop performed by each thread [Yes a `goto` but I do not really like  `while(true)` constructs since they have no semantic meaning]:

```
int Sim2d::DatablockProcessor::run()
{
m_stop=0;
next_frame:
    {
    start.wait();
    if(m_stop)
        {return STATUS_OK;}
    m_model->process(m_framecounter,m_buffers[0].first,m_buffers[0].second
        ,m_offset);
    swap(m_buffers[0],m_buffers[1]);
    ready.set();
    goto next_frame;
    }
}
```

`m_buffer` is declared as

```
BufferinfoPair m_buffers[2];
```

Inside `DatablockProcessor`

The computation of data block regions looks like this

```
double bh_avg=double(m_buffers.first.nRowsGet())/N;
uint32_t offset=uint32_t(k*bh_avg);
uint32_t height_block=uint32_t((k+1)*bh_avg) - offset;
Sim2d::BufferinfoPair buffers[2]=
    {
     {m_buffers.first,m_buffers.second,height_block,offset}
    ,{m_buffers.second,m_buffers.first,height_block,offset}
    };
```

Possible reasons I have thought of are

1. A swapping bug (causing memory collisions)
2. A bug in initiation of per thread data region (causing memory collisions)
3. Biased synchronization
4. Cache misses
5. Zero values are processed faster than other values on x86-64
6. The opposite of 5
7. Boundary conditions make time slightly longer for boundary blocks
8. Operating system observes that memory content does not change even though the code writes to it

I have excluded reasons 3, since if I try some other code (filling with white noise), I do not get the same issue.

Reason 4 is unlikely since it processes the same data over and over again.

Reason 5 can be excluded since the initial state has non-zero values in given to all threads, but the framerate *drops* when zero values appears.

Reason 6 can be excluded since during the period of slow processing, small values appears in the gradient for the majority of all pixels. So then, it would be more probable to have large CPU usage for all but one thread.

Reason 7 is excluded since it should be the same for each frame

Reason 8 may sound strange but I observe a rise in speed after the domain has been completely filled. When this happens pixel values changes everywhere. Introducing noise supports this hypotheses since noise make the problem disappear. On the other hand: Is such measurements really feasible

What is the most probable reason for the observed behavior?

EDIT:

The master thread looks like this:

```
proc_ptr=processors.begin();
while(proc_ptr!=processors.end())
    {
    proc_ptr->frameNext();
    ++proc_ptr;
    }

while(proc_ptr!=processors.begin())
    {
    --proc_ptr;
    proc_ptr->wait();
    }
```

Does this code favour some of the threads? I experimented with starting in a more random order, with no success. Another thing to note is that changing the model so it only spits out a constant like

```
    ptr_dest[k][l].u=0; //+ 0.06125*( d*l_u - v_u*v_v*v_v + F*(1-v_u) );
    ptr_dest[k][l].v=1; //+ 0.06125*( l_v + v_u*v_v*v_v - (F+ka)*v_v );
```

makes the problem disappear. I conclude that from the resulting framerate that the double loop has not been optimized out.

EDIT 2:

Stopping the simulation thread and restarting it from the current state results in the same poor performance, so I conclude that the pixel values affects the scheduling.

Comment: use a profiler, you'll see its probably due to lock contention

Comment: @paulm So you suggest that it is reason 3?

Comment: @paulm Sadly, gprof cannot help me here. It is multithreaded.

Comment: Have you ruled out false sharing?

Comment: @ChrisO The matrices are allocated as two separate large data blocks on the heap, aligned to the size of the cache line. The ValueType typedef is defined as float and the width of the matrix is 800 px which gives a size of 2*4*800 bytes per scanline. Also I have this performance boost at the end and a different model does not necessary suffer from the problem.